# MeteorJS invoking a client function and alerting result

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Trying to see how can I invoke an alert after the event is fired by clicking a button from a Meteor method call. I am able to see that the function is invoked, but seems that it is crashing on the template.find. Any thoughts h

here is the code:

```
"click .regular-button": function (event, template) {
  var show = template.find('.showinputtext').value;

  alert(show);
```

and

```
<form class="new-inputform">
      <input type="text" id="showinputtext" placeholder="Show name" />
</form>
<button class="regular-button">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the js event

```
Template.yourTemplateName.events({
  'submit .new-inputform' :function(event,template){
    event.preventDefault();
    var show = template.find('#showinputtext');
  alert($(show).val());
  }
})
```

i am using, jquery to alert the value from the input. i just change the `var show` and remove the `.classSelector` to `#idSelector`, and add the `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I wish to have my button outside of the form element. Is there still a way to do this?

Comment: But how would this work when I click a button instead? Not by submitting a form. I updated my html code above

Comment: Nevermind, all I had to use is `#` on the `showinputtext` instead of `.` Thanks!

Comment: Yep just change the Selector on the 'submit' event, glad it help you, do you need more help?